Why the default value of T of enable_if is void?
template<bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if {}; #1
 
template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; }; #2

It only declares the default value of T is void in the #1. For #2, there is not default value of T. However, why T will be void if the bool B is true?
Moreover, why it will match #1 if the bool B is false when #1 doesn't declare the struct like enable_if<false, T>.

I think you're looking for how template argument deduction work in specialization. This is explained in any beginner c++ book. Also see dupe Why void is required while declaring a class template which is to be specialized using enable_if and void_t spezialization why does primary template has to have default = void?.

Those are the basics of template specialization. "For #2, there is not default value of T." Specializations never have default template arguments, they are always taken from the primery template. "Moreover, why it will match #1 if the bool B is false" Because #1 is the primary template, it matches by default if none of the specializations match.

See the answer in How Does std::enable_if work? which explains in more detail. That should clear your query.
